# Pandas Cumsum in expanding rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Looking to learn how to code this solution in a more elegant way. Need to split a set of rows into a smaller pieces and control the utilization as well as calculate the balance. Current solution is not generating the balance properly

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

box_list = [['Box0', 0.2],
               ['Box1', 1.0],
               ['Box2', 1.8],
               ['Box4', 2.0],
               ['Box8', 4.01],]
  
sdf = pd.DataFrame(box_list, columns = ['Name', 'Size'])

print(sdf)
```

|  | Name | Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Box1 | 1.00 |
| 2 | Box2 | 1.80 |
| 3 | Box4 | 2.00 |
| 4 | Box8 | 4.01 |

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': np.repeat(sdf['Name'], sdf['Size'].apply(np.ceil)),
                    'Size': np.repeat(sdf['Size'], sdf['Size'].apply(np.ceil)),})

df['Max_Units']=df['Size'].apply(lambda x: np.ceil(x) if x>1.0 else 1.0) 
df = df.reset_index()
df['Utilization'] =df['Size'].apply(lambda x: x-int(x) if x>1.0 else (x if x<1.0 else 1.0))  
df['Balance'] =df['Max_Units'] 

g = df.groupby(['index'], as_index=0, group_keys=0)

df['Utilization'] = g.apply(lambda x: 
                           pd.Series(np.where((x.Balance.shift(1) >= 1.0), 
                           1.0, 
                           x.Utilization))).values
df.loc[(df.Utilization == 0.0), ['Utilization']] = 1.0

df['Balance'] = g.apply(lambda x: 
                           pd.Series(np.where((x.Balance.shift(1) >= 1.0), 
                           x.Max_Units-x.Utilization, 
                           0))).values
print(df)
```

|  | index | Name | Size | Max_Units | Utilization | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | Box0 | 0.20 | 1.0 | 0.20 | 0.0 |
| 1 | 1 | Box1 | 1.00 | 1.0 | 1.00 | 0.0 |
| 2 | 2 | Box2 | 1.80 | 2.0 | 0.80 | 0.0 |
| 3 | 2 | Box2 | 1.80 | 2.0 | 1.00 | 1.0 |
| 4 | 3 | Box4 | 2.00 | 2.0 | 1.00 | 0.0 |
| 5 | 3 | Box4 | 2.00 | 2.0 | 1.00 | 1.0 |
| 6 | 4 | Box8 | 4.01 | 5.0 | 0.01 | 0.0 |
| 7 | 4 | Box8 | 4.01 | 5.0 | 1.00 | 4.0 |
| 8 | 4 | Box8 | 4.01 | 5.0 | 1.00 | 4.0 |
| 9 | 4 | Box8 | 4.01 | 5.0 | 1.00 | 4.0 |
| 10 | 4 | Box8 | 4.01 | 5.0 | 1.00 | 4.0 |

Comment: *Current solution is not generating the balance properly* - what is your expected output? can you add the expected output in the question body with some explanation?

Comment: Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/9840637/anky. The Balance for the last chunk, Box8 should be like 0.0, 1,0 2.0 3.0 4.0

Comment: Can you please explain? I can only assume the last chunk to be 0,4,3,2,1 instead of 0,1,2,3,4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I completely understand what all of these values are supposed to be representing.

However, I've achieved the correct desired output for your sample set in more direct ways:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

box_list = [['Box0', 0.2],
            ['Box1', 1.0],
            ['Box2', 1.8],
            ['Box4', 2.0],
            ['Box8', 4.01], ]

df = pd.DataFrame(box_list, columns=['Name', 'Size'])

# Set ceil column to ceil of size since it's used more than once
df['ceil'] = df['Size'].apply(np.ceil)

# Duplicate Rows based on Ceil of Size
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['ceil'])]

# Get Max Units by comparing it to the ceil column
df['Max_Units'] = df.apply(lambda s: max(s['ceil'], 1), axis=1)

# Extract Decimal Portion By Using % 1 (Catch Special Case of x == 1)
df['Utilization'] = df['Size'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 1 else x % 1)

# Everywhere Max_Units cumcount is not 0 set Utilization to 1
df.loc[df.groupby(df['Max_Units']).cumcount().ne(0), 'Utilization'] = 1

# Set Balance to index cumcount as float
df['Balance'] = df.groupby(df.index).cumcount().astype(float)

# Drop Unnecessary Column and reset index for output
df = df.drop(columns=['ceil']).reset_index()

# For Display
print(df)
```

Output:

|  | index | Name | Size | Max_Units | Utilization | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | Box0 | 0.20 | 1.0 | 0.20 | 0.0 |
| 1 | 1 | Box1 | 1.00 | 1.0 | 1.00 | 0.0 |
| 2 | 2 | Box2 | 1.80 | 2.0 | 0.80 | 0.0 |
| 3 | 2 | Box2 | 1.80 | 2.0 | 1.00 | 1.0 |
| 4 | 3 | Box4 | 2.00 | 2.0 | 1.00 | 0.0 |
| 5 | 3 | Box4 | 2.00 | 2.0 | 1.00 | 1.0 |
| 6 | 4 | Box8 | 4.01 | 5.0 | 0.01 | 0.0 |
| 7 | 4 | Box8 | 4.01 | 5.0 | 1.00 | 1.0 |
| 8 | 4 | Box8 | 4.01 | 5.0 | 1.00 | 2.0 |
| 9 | 4 | Box8 | 4.01 | 5.0 | 1.00 | 3.0 |
| 10 | 4 | Box8 | 4.01 | 5.0 | 1.00 | 4.0 |